# What is best way to configure soap based web services in HTML5 based apps

Tags: java, web-services, cordova, soap, html5-canvas

I am developing banking mobile apps using html5 for client as communicate back-end system they provided soap based xml services.

1. To make a soap request, i doesn't want to write code in ".js" file because of code complexity and not found request and response logs in production phases.

   2. now i want to make separate project to maintain the web-service request and response business logic using java?
   3. from .js, I want to make a http request to call the web service as a response i want to get json an object?.

Please correct me if i was wrong, Please help me how to separate web service logic into a single project?

Note: I doesn't want to configure my soap request through js file.

Regards,
nag

Answer (score 0):

Write a servlet or httphandler(if IIS) that interacts with SOAP services and parses the information and creates a json response for the JS client.

You JS client interacts with servlet/httphandler and handles when it json response when it receives it.